# Issues deploying a simple WAR application in JBOSS 6 EAP that worked in JBOSS AS 5

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss

I have a MAVEN war file which works just fine in my old JBOSS 5.1 AS Environment. However, when I try adding the war into the JBOSSEAP/standalone/deployments directory (via the management console UI or directly), I get the following error which I'm unable to make sense of:

> 15:45:07,693 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014612: Operation ("add")
>   failed - address: ([{"deployment" => "clinicalTrials.war"}]) - failure
>   description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable
>   dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"clinicalTrials.war\".PARSE
>   is missing
>   [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"clinicalTrials.war\".WEB-INF/classes.STRUCTURE]"]}
>       15:45:07,694 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment
>   "clinicalTrials.war" was rolled back with the following failure
>   message: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies"
>   => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"clinicalTrials.war\".PARSE is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"clinicalTrials.war\".WEB-INF/classes.STRUCTURE]"]}
>       15:45:07,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name:
>   WEB-INF/classes) in 2ms
>       15:45:07,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment clinicalTrials.war
>   (runtime-name: clinicalTrials.war) in 40ms
>       15:45:07,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
>       JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>             service jboss.deployment.subunit."clinicalTrials.war".WEB-INF/classes
>   (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."clinicalTrials.war".PARSE] 
>             service jboss.deployment.subunit."clinicalTrials.war".WEB-INF/classes.STRUCTURE
>   (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."clinicalTrials.war".PARSE]

I have run a `jar tvf clinicalTrials.war` to ensure the war deployment contains all of the classes and again, this is working in my JBOSS 5 AS Environment when I plop it in the server/default/deploy directory so I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. I have set the log level to DEBUG but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the jar files that are included in the war files especially those related to Hibernate, JSF and XML parser, need to play around with WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml to make sure the correct version are loaded. Some of the jars under the modules are automatically loaded base on the presences of certain files in the war (see JBoss documentation on Module). This could suppress the local version from loading under the local lib causing the error.